# Loss of the label after using mutate and recode (dplyr) of a character class variable

Tags: r, label, dplyr, recode

Again and again I have to search the internet when it comes to label my dataframe variables. For me this is not a trivial issue when doing it in the context with dplyr.

Using the set_label function from sjlabelled package I have learned to create a label vector and pass it to the variables of the dataframe. But then something unexpected happened.

For demonstration purposes I have modified the iris dataset (changed the class of Species to character).
I would like to know why the label of the variable Species disappears in case of Species as character class (case1) and remains in case of Species as factor class (case 2, commented out in the code) - after using mutate and recode.

case 1 (Species=character class):
[image]

case 2 (Species=factor class):
[image]

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjlabelled) # set_label function
# vector for variable names
label_names <- c("Length of sepal", "Width of Sepal", "Length of Petal", "Width of Petal", "A lot of Species")

# case 1
# change Species class to character for demonstrating
iris$Species <- as.character(iris$Species)

# case 2
# iris$Species <- as.factor(iris$Species)

iris_new <- iris %>% 
    set_label(label = label_names) %>% 
    mutate(Species = dplyr::recode(Species, 
                                 "setosa" = "setosa_new",
                                 "versicolor" = "versicolorandvirginica", 
                                 "virginica" = "versicolorandvirginica"))
```

and additionally:

how can I use this simple code
`label(iris$Species) <- "A lot of Species"`
in a dplyr workflow to just label one variable by one.
Thank you!

Comment: I guess in the second case with `character`, it is using the `recode.character` while in the first, it is `recode.factor`.  If you check the `str` of output before the `recode`, it does retain the label whether it is factor or character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've found a bug, or rather a lack of compatibility. `dplyr::recode` seems to remove the `label` attribute.

```
iris %>% 
    set_label(label = label_names) %>%
    pull(Species) %>% attributes()
#$label
#           Species 
#"A lot of Species"

iris %>% 
  set_label(label = label_names) %>% 
  mutate(Species = dplyr::recode(Species, 
                                 "setosa" = "setosa_new",
                                 "versicolor" = "versicolorandvirginica", 
                                 "virginica" = "versicolorandvirginica")) %>%
  pull(Species) %>% attributes()
#NULL
```

If we review the [source](https://rdrr.io/cran/dplyr/src/R/recode.R) for `dplyr::recode`, we find it is because for character vectors, there is a call to `as.character`, which removes the attributes. Meanwhile the factor method has no such call.

But to answer your last question, there is a version of `set_label` that is intended to relabel one or more columns of a data frame, `var_labels`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(sjlabelled)
iris %>% 
  set_label(label = label_names) %>% 
  mutate(Species = dplyr::recode(Species, 
                                 "setosa" = "setosa_new",
                                 "versicolor" = "versicolorandvirginica", 
                                 "virginica" = "versicolorandvirginica")) %>%
  var_labels(Species = "A lot of Species") %>%
  View()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect. And who will care now about the bug or rather the lack of compatibility?